# Adobe AEM - How can I return a custom error page after a post fails?

Tags: java, aem, httpresponse

I've created an overwriting of the foundation Forms where I'm trying to return an error page that is configured by the author within the component
In other words, the flow would be:
- author configure error page
- the end user submits the form
- the form process fails
- aem returns the error page configured by the author with status 500

at the moment i've overwritten the forward.jsp. JSPs that are used by the different Foundation Form actions. This jsp performs a forward to the servlet that processes the data entered by the end user, here is the line that performs the forward:

```
FormsHelper.setForwardPath (slingRequest, resource.getPath () + "." + Constants.SERVLET_SELECTOR + ".html");
```

On the servlet i have a code similar to:

```
String errorPage = request.getParameter(":errorPage");
...
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(errorPage)) {
    response.reset();
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    response.setStatus(statusCode);
    final RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(erroPage);

    if (dispatcher != null) {
        try {
            dispatcher.include(new GetRequest(request), response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.debug("Exception swallowed while including error page", e);
        }
    }

private static class GetRequest extends SlingHttpServletRequestWrapper {
    public GetRequest(SlingHttpServletRequest wrappedRequest) {
        super(wrappedRequest);
    }

    public String getMethod() {
        return "GET";
    }
}
```

It seems to work, but since it is a forward, the parameters are sent to the response, which would not be necessary and i think a bad practice.
What would be the correct way to do it without making a forward, being able to return the error page and with status 500 in the response.?

Comment: Where is the “:error” parameter set? If you are setting it, then you could instead set a request attribute instead of a parameter. Alternatively, don’t set a parameter at all and have a dedicated servlet to serve the error page. Meaning, you don’t need a custom param or attribute, calling the servelt means the form encountered an error.

Comment: Hi @AhmedMusallam thanks!, the errorPage is added on the custom start.jsp(foundation)
`final String errorPage = properties.get("errorPage", "");`
`<input type="hidden" name=":errorPage" value="<%= xssAPI.encodeForHTMLAttr(URLDecoder.decode(errorPage,"UTF-8")) %>">`
The servlet is dedicated to process the submission of the form, that is, depending on the configuration, the servlet can send an email to the administrator or save the data in a Google spreadsheet. In case of an error in any of the processes, the servlet must return the error page that the author configured in the form component.

Comment: How exactly is your post request handled? Is it a specific path that’s always fixed regardless of where the form component is authored? Or is it a resource type? (Ie the path to your specific component)?